# python3 has different directory as pip3

Tags: pip, python-3.7

I have install python3 using homebrew on my MacOS and when I run "which python3" is shows "/anaconda3/bin/python3". when is run "which pip3" it shows "/usr/local/bin/pip3".

so when I install packages using pip3, I will never use it since python3 links to anaconda3 environment. how can I link my python3 to my pip3 ?

I'm using zsh not bash if that matters

Comment: what did ```python3 -m pip``` gives output?

Comment: Usage:
  /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7 -m pip <command> [options]

Comment: Try installing your modules via ```python3 -m pip install module_name```...